# Out of space while building android Rom

Tags: android, rom

I'm getting the below error while making system.img

there are all files like boot.img, vendor.img but not system img

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

> set_selinux_xattr: No such file or directory searching for label
>   "/bt_firmware" e2fsdroid: No such file or directory while configuring
>   the file system loaded 3450 fs_config entries
>
> Out of space? Out of inodes? The tree size of
>   /home/prashi_kadasi/arrow10/out/soong/.temp/tmpP2XFd3 is 1272721408
>   bytes (1213 MB), with reserved space of 0 bytes (0 MB). The max image
>   size for filesystem files is 4294967296 bytes (4096 MB), out of a
>   total partition size of 4294967296 bytes (4096 MB). 01:24:45 ninja
>   failed with: exit status 1
>
> failed to build some targets (01:02 (mm:ss))

Answer (score 4):

Check that you include this

```
/bt_firmware(/.*)?                                      u:object_r:bt_firmware_file:s0
```

in your file_contexts and this

```
type bt_firmware_file, file_type;
```

in your file.te (and that you have your sepolicy included)

Comment: Also make sure all the paths are correct - sometimes in these sepolicy.mk files are optional includes (e. g. `-include device/lineage/sepolicy/qcom/sepolicy.mk`) which you might need to correct.

Answer (score 1):

I know the solution to this was given for the most part, but I see this asked quite a lot and I figure this a good place to give a little background.

So the answer is usually given in some form of "add the offending label to file_contexts and and make sure its labeled", apart from that, rebuilding file_contexts and sepolicy/sepolicy.recovery and starting a new build fixes it.

The issue stems fro selabel_lookup failing, and in my experience this is usually due to additions to device trees and or changes that weren't accounted for before file_contexts.bin is created by the build system. You can learn a lot more about the issue from this now obscure [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/e2fsprogs/+/87a7db7cf2ca0feecaccad94bf22f92c726000c3)